# How to change database data on second page based on what i select for the dropdownlist on the first page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have this 2 tables called room and schedule which have relationship with each other. Currently I only have lecture Room type. After clicking lecture in the first drop down list in mainmenu.aspx, the second dropdownlist will populate whatever rooms that belongs to lecture.

The problem is whatever rooms i clicked, either L338, L339 or L340, it always gives me the same output data on the timetable.(using daypilot control for the output) The output that I would like to achieve will be, L338 will come out only Lecture on network data, L339 will come out only Lecture on english data, and L340 will come out lecture on Chinese data.(see database data)

The room number on the title for number2.aspx will always changed because i stored it in a session on the mainmenu.aspx second dropdownlist, that's why the room number will always change. But I don't know how to make the data to always change based on the room number i select. helppppp pls

**Room table and relationship with schedule table**
[image]

**Schedule table**
[image]

**Main Menu.aspx**
[image]

**number2.aspx for L338**
[image]

**number2.aspx for L339**
[image]

**Mainmenu.aspx**

```
public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct ROOM_TYPE from ROOM", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlRoomType.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ROOM_TYPE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlRoomType.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlRoomType.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

            ddlRoomType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select type", "0"));
        }

        ddlRoom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }


    protected void ddlRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projectConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct ROOM_CODE from Room where ROOM_TYPE='" + ddlRoomType.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

        ddlRoom.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ROOM_CODE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        // to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlRoom.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlRoom.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist

        ddlRoom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select room", "0"));
    }

    protected void ddlRoom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["roomvalue"] = ddlRoom.SelectedValue;

            Response.Redirect("number2.aspx");
    }
}
```

**Number2.aspx**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblVenue.Text = Session["roomvalue"] != null ? Session["roomvalue"].ToString() : "";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 04, 03));
            //DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days);
            DataBind();
        }

    }

    private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, PURPOSE, [START_DATE], [END_DATE], [START_TIME], [END_TIME] FROM [Schedule]", constr);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["START_TIME"]);
            dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["END_TIME"]);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(object date, object time)
    {
        if (date == null)
        {
            // Add some logic for this scenario. Here are 2 examples:
            //throw new ArgumentNullException("date");
            //date = DateTime.MaxValue;
        }
        if (time == null)
        {
            // Add some logic for this scenario.
            //throw new ArgumentNullException("time");
            //time = 0;
        }

        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        float hoursAndMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(time);

        return CombineDateAndTime(dt, hoursAndMinutes);
    }
    public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(DateTime date, float time)
    {
        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)time / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        float remainder = time - (hours * 100);
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)remainder, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        DateTime returnDate = date.Date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
        return returnDate;
    }
}
```

**Following @Trafz advice**

**once i right click execute query, it pop up this. I guess this must be value of L338, L339 or L340? I entered L338 and click ok.**

[image]

**came out no data. I also tried putting a debug point on  return dt; came out 0 count under rows**

[image]

**SELECT * FROM [Schedule] s JOIN [room] r ON r.ROOM_CODE = s.ROOM_CODE**

[image]

**Current codes**

```
public partial class number2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblVenue.Text = Session["roomvalue"] != null ? Session["roomvalue"].ToString() : "";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 04, 03));
            //DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days, lblVenue.Text);
            DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days, string roomValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roomValue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("roomValue");

        const string sql = @"
SELECT
    s.ID,
    PURPOSE,
    [START_DATE],
    [END_DATE],
    [START_TIME],
    [END_TIME]
FROM [Schedule] s
    JOIN [room] r ON r.ROOM_CODE = s.ROOM_CODE
WHERE r.ROOM_TYPE = @SelectedRoomType";

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, constr);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedRoomType", roomValue);

        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["START_TIME"]);
            dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["END_TIME"]);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(object date, object time)
    {
        if (date == null)
        {
            // Add some logic for this scenario. Here are 2 examples:
            //throw new ArgumentNullException("date");
            //date = DateTime.MaxValue;
        }
        if (time == null)
        {
            // Add some logic for this scenario.
            //throw new ArgumentNullException("time");
            //time = 0;
        }

        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        float hoursAndMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(time);

        return CombineDateAndTime(dt, hoursAndMinutes);
    }
    public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(DateTime date, float time)
    {
        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)time / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        float remainder = time - (hours * 100);
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)remainder, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        DateTime returnDate = date.Date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
        return returnDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the name of the "Room table"?

Comment: the Room table is called room lols. I mention it in my question>>>>(I have this 2 tables called room and schedule). it is also shown on the first screenshot, wonder why you couldn't find it @Trafz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do multiple things if you want your database to only return specific data depending on some value.

So firstly, you should send the needed parameter from your Page_Load to your `dbGetEvents()` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblVenue.Text = Session["roomvalue"] != null ? Session["roomvalue"].ToString() : "";

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 04, 03));
        //DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date);
        DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days, lblVenue.Text);
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

But we haven't told the database what to do with the value. Currently, you just select all dates:

```
"SELECT ID, PURPOSE, [START_DATE], [END_DATE], [START_TIME], [END_TIME] FROM [Schedule]"
```

So we need to `JOIN` your tables together in order to get the dates from the roomtypes:

```
"SELECT ID, PURPOSE, [START_DATE], [END_DATE], [START_TIME], [END_TIME] FROM [Schedule]
    JOIN [rooms] ON [rooms].ROOM_CODE = [Schedule].ROOM_CODE"
```

But that's not all. We need to filter those results with the roomtype the user selected. So you add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE [rooms].ROOM_CODE = Session["roomvalue"]
```

That would work, but that's very low security. Because some hacker might type in some SQL in that `Session["roomvalue"]` and run that on your database. So we need to add it as a `parameter` instead:

```
WHERE [rooms].ROOM_CODE = @SelectedRoomCode
```

But the database doesn't know the value for the parameter `@SelectedRoomType`, so we need to tell it by adding this bottom line to your `dbGetEvents()`:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, constr);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedRoomCode", roomValue);
```

But if someone visited `Numbers2.aspx` without that Session value, then they wouldn't get any results back from the server, so we KNOW that it would just be a waste of ressources. So I'm adding this in the top of `dbGetEvents()` as well:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roomValue))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("roomValue");
```

So to sum it all up, here's what I changed:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblVenue.Text = Session["roomvalue"] != null ? Session["roomvalue"].ToString() : "";

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 04, 03));
                //DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date);
                DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days, lblVenue.Text);
                DataBind();
            }
        }

        private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days, string roomValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roomValue))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("roomValue");

            const string sql = @"
SELECT
    s.ID,
    PURPOSE,
    [START_DATE],
    [END_DATE],
    [START_TIME],
    [END_TIME]
FROM [Schedule] s
    JOIN [rooms] r ON r.ROOM_CODE = s.ROOM_CODE
WHERE r.ROOM_CODE = @SelectedRoomCode";

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, constr);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedRoomCode", roomValue);

            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["START_TIME"]);
                dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["END_TIME"]);
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Replace the `[rooms]` name in the `sql` variable with the actual table name. I couldn't find it in your question, @Jordjmax

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why you couldn;t find the table name. It's called room. Isn;t it in the first screenshot? I changed rooms to room, but got a empty timetable for L338, L339 and L340. I will try figure it first @Trafz

Comment: I tried to do some of the troubleshooting methods u taught me before. Edited post above. It means there's a problem in the query am i right? @Trafz

Comment: You're progressing quite well and you're right. It means there's a problem with either the query or the data. So lets test the query first. Remove the `WHERE` clause and see if you get any data then.

Comment: Thanks. image added. Data came out. @Trafz

Comment: Replace the columns in the `SELECT` with `*`. Then we'll be able to see the ROOM_TYPE the query produces.

Comment: Like this ? SELECT *
FROM [Schedule] s
    JOIN [room] r ON r.ROOM_CODE = s.ROOM_CODE

Comment: Yes. That'll give us all the data we have to work with.

Comment: Oh, another mistake on my part. Use my original SQL again, but change the `WHERE` clause from `WHERE r.ROOM_TYPE = @SelectedRoomType"` to `WHERE r.ROOM_CODE = @SelectedRoomType"`. It would also be nice if you changed `@SelectedRoomType` to `@SelectedRoomCode` in the query + the place where we add the value as a parameter.

Comment: thanks completed. whoa u r sick? that's why u didn't go to work or something? and help out people here. 2moro monday, gonna try use the codes on the school server database, hope it goes well. I created all these tables to test only. @Trafz

Comment: I actually am, yeah.
You might run into trouble when you're using the school's database, because the datatypes or column names might be different. But you're already able to debug your application well enough to spot where the error might be, so maybe your teacher will be impressed enough to help you fix the final issues if any pop up.

Comment: the database datatypes will be the same think unless i am careless. Previously I tried 2 datetime column fields. Until my teacher told me to use the school server database which is in float datatype and datetime database, so I have to create a identifical table datatypes so that i can work at home, but it is already converted which was solve by you. @Trafz